# Inserting variables inside .add_argument version

Tags: python, python-2.7

Currently I use

```
parser.add_argument('--version', action='version', version='%(prog)s 1.0')
```

I'd like to have the '1.0' to be a variable.

I tried various things with no luck...

Comment: Are you asking how to join strings together?

Comment: Within a function call, yes. Sorry if it's n00bish, I haven't slept in a while and I'm just getting to grips to python on a project written in something I'm more at home with.

Comment: It wasn't that it's *n00bish*, just the question wasn't too clear.

Comment: ah! no problem Latty :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use string formatting:

```
version = '1.0'
parser.add_argument('--version', action='version', version='%(prog)s {}'.format(version))
```

The version of your program is not going to change during it's (short, showing commandline help only) lifetime, so you only need to interpolate this *once*.

Comment: Thank you. Will mark this as answer in 7 minutes. Pheww that was fast :)